# Naming an abstract class that extends another abstract class

Tags: java, naming-conventions

What is a good naming convention for an abstract class that extends another abstract class?

I've got an abstract class called `Builder`, how should I name the abstract class that extends it? Should I name the first class `AbstractBuilder` and the sublass `AbstractBuilderImpl`?

Thanks!

Comment: What if `AbstractBuilder` is extended by another abstract class?

Comment: @ernest_k _AbstractAbstractBuilder_ :D .

Comment: I wouldn't use the _Impl_ suffix, as that usually represents a concrete, not abstract, class.

Comment: what does the extending class do, what does it add? its surely not just extending the abstract class, for fun...

Comment: The fact that it's abstract shouldn't matter. Builder is a too vague name. You should name the class based on what it is, not on whether it's abstract or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that most of the time its more about using logic than conventions - think about what Builder is, what AbstractBuilder is and name accordingly. Do you need to state that AbstractBuilder is abstract, does it have any real impact? A more suitable name would probably be based on its purpose and the added functionality.

Lets say you have abstract class Employee and extending it are abstract classes HourlyEmployee and SalariedEmployee - that just makes sense right? It gives you a better idea of purpose than AbstractEmployee1/2 would.

On implementations itself - Yea, I've seen corporations use xxxImpl - so I guess its usable, but again - it depends on the class itself and what it brings - there might be a better name out there that you can come up with or there might not, but xxxImpl will serve just as well.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a generic name for each class you can use another approach,e.g, something like **Vehicle** for the main class (Builder) and then **'LandVehicle' or 'FlyingVehicle'** for the (AbstractBuilder) and then **'Car' or 'PoweredParagliding'** for the last class of this tree (AbstractBuilderImpl)